# Can't see repo after "git svn clone <url>" on Mac Leopard

Tags: macos, git-svn

We use SVN here at the office and I'm experimenting with using git-svn for myself.

I created a directory in /usr/local/code/git and did my checkout to /testco.

I used the commands given in the man page, git svn clone , where  is my repo.

It goes through a few hundred lines of all the files in the SVN trunk, but when its done the directory only contains a .git file. None of the other files are there. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something resembling the following:

```
git svn init -t foo/tags -b foo/branches -T foo/trunk path_to_repo
git svn fetch
```

For a really good intro to `git-svn`, check out [`git-svn` is a Gateway Drug](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2008/04/10/git-svn-is-a-gateway-drug).

Answer (score 0):

looks like git forgets to checkout your files. do:

```
git checkout master
```